# C++ - back to start of loop without checking the condition

Tags: c++, perl, loops, redo

Programming on perl, we can use a smart function named 'redo' - we can go back to the start of the loop, without looking at the condition. It's useful when, for example, we create a table in which we must to set a expected values/characters (e.g. "a-b-c", nothing else).
I would like to ask if exist in C++ function like that. I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: I cannot imagine a use case for that which cannot be served with the usual constructs (`if`, `while`, etc). Please provide a minimal example

Comment: For example: we have an array we want to fill in specific characters (only "a" or "b"). If we wouldn't use 'goto' after writing incorrect value, the condition would be rechecked (or... I don't know better option). As a result - our counter would be increased (instead of write tab[i] again, wrote badly before, we would write tab[i+1])

Comment: what's wrong with a `while` loop? as in `char x=0; while(is_wrong(x=obtain())); table[i]=x;`

Comment: We can do it in this way too, but isn't using a 'goto' more intuitive in this situation? (knowing, that this command isn't recommended usually)

Comment: `goto` is **never** intuitive, since the label and the `goto` statement are in general not related in a structural way. With `do` there is always a `while`, an associated block of execution and a condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no redo keyword for going back to the start of a loop, but there's no reason you couldn't do it with `goto`. (Oh I feel so dirty recommending `goto`...)

```
int tries = 0;
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
  loop_start:
  bool ok = ((i+tries)%3==0);
  if(ok) {
     ++tries;
     goto loop_start;
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the the same operation before the moment :). Works good. So, we couldn't do it shortly?

Answer (score 3):

I think a more reasonable solution is

```
int trie=0;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    while((i+tries)%3==0 {
         ++tries;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid `goto` at any cost,

```
int tries = 0;
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {do{

  bool redo = ((i+tries)%3 == 0);

  if (redo) { ++tries; }
  else      { break; }

} while(1); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can you not use a simple `while` loop?

```
auto is_okay = [](char x) { return x=='a' || x=='b'; };
container C;
for(std::size_t i=0; i!=C.size(); ++i) {
  char x;
  while(!is_okay(x=obtain_new_character()));  // get new x until it's okay
  C[i]=x;
}
```

Or, equivalently, a `do while` loop

```
container C;
for(std::size_t i=0; i!=C.size(); ++i) {
  char x;
  do {
    x=obtain_new_character();
  } while(x!='a' && x!='b');
  C[i]=x;
}
```

Or even a `for` loop

```
container C;
for(std::size_t i=0; i!=C.size(); ++i) {
  char x=0;
  for(; x!='a' && a!='b'; x=obtain_new_character());
  C[i]=x;
}
```